# Erro ao inserir dados JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Estou tendo o seguinte problema, quero inserir os dados da minha tabela despesa mas acontece algum erro com a minha foreign key, o que pode ser ?

> despesaDao: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`trabalhoviagemd`.`despesa`, CONSTRAINT `despesa_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`idViagem`) REFERENCES `viagem` (`idViagem`))

***Método inserir do Dao***

```
 public class DespesaDao {
    private final static String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    private static final int QTDE = 10; // Constante = quantidade de endereços;
    private static DespesaBean vetor[] = new DespesaBean[QTDE];
    private static final String cabecalho = "idViagem,tipoDespesa, valorDespesa, dataDespesa\n";

    public static boolean inserir(DespesaBean despesa) {
        boolean executou = false;
        if (ConexaoMySQL.conectar()) {
            try {
                Connection con = ConexaoMySQL.getConexao();
                String sql = "Insert into despesa values (0,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement P = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                P.setInt(1, despesa.getIdViagem());
                P.setString(2, despesa.getTipoDespesa());
                P.setDouble(3, despesa.getValorDespesa());
                P.setString(4,DataHelper.CalendarToString(DATE_FORMAT,despesa.getDataDespesa()));

                P.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("despesaDao.inserir:\n" + P);
                P.close();
                executou = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("despesaDao: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ConexaoMySQL.fecharConexao();
            }

        }
        return executou;
    }
```

***Tabelas Do banco***

```
 CREATE TABLE viagem (
   idViagem INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   tipoViagem VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
   dataInicio DATE NOT NULL,
   dataEncerramento DATE NOT NULL,
   cidade VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
   uf VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
   valorDiaria DOUBLE NOT NULL,
   colaborador VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   cliente VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`idViagem`));

   select * from viagem;

 CREATE TABLE despesa (
    idDespesa INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idViagem INT NOT NULL,
    tipoDespesa VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    valorDespesa DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    dataDespesa DATE NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (idViagem) REFERENCES trabalhoviagemd.viagem(idViagem));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é simples: ao tentar inserir seu registro na tabela `despesa`, você está tentando inserir no campo `idViagem` um valor que **NÃO existe** na tabela `viagem`.

Sua chave estrangeira (`foreign key`) `despesa.idViagem` provavelmente está configurada para `RESTRICT`, ou seja, se algum dado for inserido na tabela que contém a chave estrangeira, este dado estrangeiro (no caso `despesa.idViagem`) deve **OBRIGATORIAMENTE** existir na tabela correspondente (no caso, `viagem.idViagem`).

Em outras palavras, o valor `1` não existe no campo `idViagem` da tabela `viagem`.

**Exemplo: Errado**

**tabela `viagem`**

```
idViagem | tipoViagem | dataInicio | dataEncerramento | cidade | uf | valorDiaria | colaborador | cliente
1        | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
2        | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
3        | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
```

**tabela `despesa`**

```
idDespesa | idViagem                                        | tipoDespesa | valorDespesa | dataDespesa
1         | 1   (correto, viagem.idViagem = 1 existe)       | ...         | ...          | ...
2         | 2   (correto, viagem.idViagem = 2 existe)       | ...         | ...          | ...
3         | 3   (correto, viagem.idViagem = 3 existe)       | ...         | ...          | ...
4         | 100 (errado, viagem.idViagem = 100) não existe  | ...         | ...          | ...
5         | 101 (errado, viagem.idViagem = 101) não existe) | ...         | ...          | ...
```

---

**Exemplo: Correto**

**tabela `viagem`**

```
idViagem | tipoViagem | dataInicio | dataEncerramento | cidade | uf | valorDiaria | colaborador | cliente
1        | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
2        | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
3        | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
100      | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
101      | ...        | ...        | ...              | ...    | ...| ...         | ...         | ...
```

**tabela `despesa`**

```
idDespesa | idViagem                                    | tipoDespesa | valorDespesa | dataDespesa
1         | 1   (correto, viagem.idViagem = 1 existe)   | ...         | ...          | ...
2         | 2   (correto, viagem.idViagem = 2 existe)   | ...         | ...          | ...
3         | 3   (correto, viagem.idViagem = 3 existe)   | ...         | ...          | ...
4         | 100 (correto, viagem.idViagem = 100 existe) | ...         | ...          | ...
5         | 101 (correto, viagem.idViagem = 101 existe) | ...         | ...          | ...
```

Comment: Nossa cara desculpa ter que fazer você escrever essa resposta completa por um erro tão simples, é que no meu main eu esqueci de setar o idViagem ou seja não tinha input para o usuário entrar com o número do id da viagem, se eu pudesse te daria 100+ pontos de recompensa, mas muito obrigado pelo seu suporte cara ajudou bastante no entendimento ;-)

Comment: hahahaha imagina! Sou meio detalhista mesmo! Não sabia seu nível de conhecimento pra deixar só o texto kkk Abraço

Comment: Valeu cara abraço!